# function to capitalize first chars of each word in string

Tags: javascript, capitalize

This is an attempt to capitalize "last name, first name" but it doesn't work. I can't figure out why it won't work. Can you help me with this?

```
function validateForm() {

  var memName = document.getElementById('mem-name').value;
  var memRating = document.getElementById('mem-rating').value;
  var memClass = document.getElementById('mem-class').value;

  if (memName == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  if (memRating == "") {
    alert("Rating must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  if (memClass == "") {
    alert("Class must be filled out");
    return false;
  }

  capitalize_Words(memName);

  //capitalize_Words 
  function capitalize_Words(memName) {
    return memName.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
  }

  members.push({
    Name: memName,
    Class: memClass,
    Rating: memRating,
  });

  let temp = "New player added: " + memName;
  alert(temp);
  document.getElementById("newMember").reset();

}
```

Comment: Choose one: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+function+to+capitalize+first+chars+of+each+word+in+string+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: [Seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/6cxom5jg/). What output/error are you getting?

Comment: ... also how are you using it?

Comment: http://verlager.com/super-dev.php line 185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable; simply calling `capitalize_Words(memName);` which calls `replace` on the string doesn't change the string, it just *returns the new string*. Your code is calling `capitalize_Words` and ignoring the result; store the result in a variable instead.

```
function validateForm() {
  const memName = document.getElementById('mem-name').value;
  const memRating = document.getElementById('mem-rating').value;
  const memClass = document.getElementById('mem-class').value;
  if (memName == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  if (memRating == "") {
    alert("Rating must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  if (memClass == "") {
    alert("Class must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  const capitalizedMemName = capitalize_Words(memName);
  function capitalize_Words(memName) {
    return memName.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
  }
  members.push({
    Name: capitalizedMemName,
    Class: memClass,
    Rating: memRating,
  });
  const temp = "New player added: " + memName;
  alert(temp);
  document.getElementById("newMember").reset();
}
```